# Extend a superclass from different packages

Tags: java, import, package, protected

My goal is to test the access level modifier protected, in definition, protected member can be accessed through any class in the same package and any subclass in any package.

Suppose I have a test1 class in java project test1

```
public class test {
    protected int id;
    protected String Name;
    private int age;

public test(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.Name = name;
    this.age = 10;
    }

public void setAge() {
    this.age = 20;
    }
}
```

And I have a another class test2 in java project test2, since they are from different java projects, so they are from different packages

```
public class test2 extends test {

}
```

But there is a error in test2, it says "test cannot be resolved to a type", How can I fix this? Should I write some import statements? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any use of [a class from another package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html), you can either use an import statement:

```
import com.foo.bar.whatever.test;
```

or fully-qualify the classname:

```
public class test2 extends com.foo.bar.whatever.test {
```

Incidentally, Java classes conventionally begin with an uppercase letter, i.e. `Test` and `Test2`, not `test` and `test2`.

Comment: what is foo? and bar?

Comment: It's just an example. I have no idea what you fully-qualified package name is. For example, `import java.util.ArrayList;` is how you import `ArrayList` from the `java.util` package.

Answer (score -1):

You should have both classes together in one package and write a statement like so at the very beginning of your classfile:

```
package projectname.packagename; 

public class test {
...
}
```

```java
package projectname.packagename;  
import projectname.packagename.test; 

public class test2 extends test {
...
}
```

Comment: 1) You can't always move classes to the same package, either logically or practically. For example, how would you extend `java.util.AbstractList` by this method; 2) It's unnecessary to import classes from the same package.